# Neo4j's SPARQL plugin doesn't work, etc

Tags: neo4j

I'm a newbie to Neo4j, which is at the moment my main candidate of all the graph databases out there. I'm writing a thesis about integrating a database to a smart city, and Neo4j is one of the best candidates for this purpose, if not the best.

However, I'm unable to get Neo4j's SPARQL plugin working. I'm a newbie also to Maven, but I was able to download the plugin from GitHub and compile it - however, I had to skip the tests to be able to compile it. Anyway, 'build success.'

I followed the instructions

http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/sparql-plugin/

and I suppose that I was able to insert the example quads (example 1) to my database:

> curl -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json -H Accept:application/json --data-binary @sampledata.txt -v `http:// l o c a l h o s t :7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/insert_quad`

Response:

```
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7474 (#0)
> POST /db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/insert_quad HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:7474
> Content-Type:application/json
> Accept:application/json
> Content-Length: 130
> 
* upload completely sent off: 130 out of 130 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
* Server Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815) is not blacklisted
< Server: Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

However, I cannot find that quad in my database. I suppose that a query 'MATCH (n) RETURN n LIMIT 100' would show them, right? Anyway, I only find one node with one property, 'value: urn:com.tinkerpop.blueprints.pgm.oupls.sail:namespaces.' When I try querying (example 2):

> curl -X POST -H Content-Type:application/json -H Accept:application/json --data-binary @sampledata.txt -v http:// l o c a l h o s t :7474/db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/execute_sparql

Response:

> - Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
> - Trying 127.0.0.1...
> - Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 7474 (#0)
>
> > POST /db/data/ext/SPARQLPlugin/graphdb/execute_sparql HTTP/1.1
> >     User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> >     Host: localhost:7474
> >     Content-Type:application/json
> >     Accept:application/json
> >     Content-Length: 74
> >
> > upload completely sent off: 74 out of 74 bytes < HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error < Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8 <
> >     Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * < Content-Length: 3274
> >
> > Server Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815) is not blacklisted < Server: Jetty(9.0.5.v20130815) <  {   "message" :
> >     "org.openrdf.query.algebra.Var.setConstant(Z)V",   "exception" :
> >     "NoSuchMethodError",   "fullname" : "java.lang.NoSuchMethodError",
> >     "stacktrace" : [
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.createConstVar(TupleExprBuilder.java:340)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.mapValueExprToVar(TupleExprBuilder.java:271)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.visit(TupleExprBuilder.java:1512)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ASTPathSequence.jjtAccept(ASTPathSequence.java:20)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.visit(TupleExprBuilder.java:1323)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ASTPathAlternative.jjtAccept(ASTPathAlternative.java:18)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.visit(TupleExprBuilder.java:1875)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ASTPropertyListPath.jjtAccept(ASTPropertyListPath.java:18)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(SimpleNode.java:157)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ASTVisitorBase.visit(ASTVisitorBase.java:979)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ASTTriplesSameSubjectPath.jjtAccept(ASTTriplesSameSubjectPath.java:18)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(SimpleNode.java:157)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ASTVisitorBase.visit(ASTVisitorBase.java:421)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ASTBasicGraphPattern.jjtAccept(ASTBasicGraphPattern.java:19)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.visit(TupleExprBuilder.java:1144)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ASTGraphPatternGroup.jjtAccept(ASTGraphPatternGroup.java:19)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.SimpleNode.childrenAccept(SimpleNode.java:157)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ASTVisitorBase.visit(ASTVisitorBase.java:1021)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ASTWhereClause.jjtAccept(ASTWhereClause.java:19)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.visit(TupleExprBuilder.java:389)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.visit(TupleExprBuilder.java:228)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ASTSelectQuery.jjtAccept(ASTSelectQuery.java:19)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.visit(TupleExprBuilder.java:378)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.TupleExprBuilder.visit(TupleExprBuilder.java:228)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.ast.ASTQueryContainer.jjtAccept(ASTQueryContainer.java:21)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.SPARQLParser.buildQueryModel(SPARQLParser.java:210)",
> >     "org.openrdf.query.parser.sparql.SPARQLParser.parseQuery(SPARQLParser.java:164)",
> >     "org.neo4j.server.plugin.sparql.SPARQLPlugin.executeSPARQL(SPARQLPlugin.java:68)",
> >     "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)",
> >     "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginMethod.invoke(PluginMethod.java:61)",
> >     "org.neo4j.server.plugins.PluginManager.invoke(PluginManager.java:159)",
> >     "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:312)",
> >     "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.ExtensionService.invokeGraphDatabaseExtension(ExtensionService.java:134)",
> >     "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)",
> >     "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)",
> >     "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)" ]
> >
> > Connection #0 to host localhost left intact

I'm wondering what could be causing this kind of behavior. I have tried SPARQL plugin with many configurations, according to all the instructions I have found, but the plugin just refuses to work.

By the way, I'm wondering is it suitable for production use. Can someone comment on this?

Perhaps there are more ways than one to get RDF working in Neo4j? As I'm a newbie to Neo4j, I'm, of course, interested in solutions that are somewhat easy to install and tailor. Well, first and foremost, they should really work in production use.

Neo4j is working otherwise just great! REST API works just fine, but I would like to compare it with the SPARQL endpoint if possible.

Comment: Looks like a version conflict with `org.openrdf.query.algebra.Var.setConstant`

Comment: In general, I think you already posted to the google group. So please don't cross post if possible.

Comment: Oh, sorry about it, Michael. I thought that my message wasn't delivered.